# Imager fails to write to CM3 eMMC

Tags: image, compute-module-3

I am trying to flash an image onto a Compute Module 3+ with onboard eMMC using the CM I/O board. The process seems straightforward, but I'm running into an error. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Ensure J4 jumper is set to EN.
2. Connect first micro USB port to host PC.
3. Connect second micro USB port to power.
4. On host PC, run `sudo ./rpiboot`.
5. On host PC, run `rpi-imager`.
6. Select image file (any).
7. Select SD card: `RPi-MSD- 0001 (raspberrypi) - 31.3 GB`
8. Select `WRITE`.

Almost immediately, it displays an error with the following text:

```
Write error while trying to zero out last part of card.
Card could be advertising wrong capacity (possibly counterfeit).
```

Searching the internet for that error message I didn't find any information. Is it just a hardware failure? Does anybody have any ideas or things I can try to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I was connecting the USB cord to the host PC through a USB hub. When I connected directly to the host without the hub, everything worked correctly. I'm not sure why the hub causes a failure since everything else that's connected to it works fine. But I'm thankfully able to continue working now.